# Why are there "template_" and "theme_" prefixes instead one?

Tags: theming

What's the difference between these ones in function names? I can overwrite each one in template.php, so?

Comment: You've missed a bit off that...it's `template_process_`/`template_preprocess_`. That's the difference - one is a theme function, one is process/preprocess function for the theme

Comment: So they used the word "template" instead of "theme" only to avoid names conflicts?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's a good question! I can't comment on the motivation for naming those functions (they go back a few Drupal versions, before my time with the CMS) but I _think_ it's a throwback from Drupal 5/6 php_template conventions or something similar. I've never questioned why they did it, just learnt which one to use when and where :)

Comment: What makes it slightly more confusing is that you can use `MYMODULE_` instead of `template_` or `theme_` in a custom module for any module you write.  So, essentially you can treat either of these as `hook_` in a module.  This isn't something I have a good grip on myself. I think I need to re-read @kiamlaluno's response a time or two more.  Interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

The functions whose name start with theme_ are theme hooks, while the functions whose name start with template_ are preprocess and process functions implemented by the module that implements the relative theme hook.

For example, [theme_image()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) is a theme hook that renders an image.   [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) is the preprocess function implemented by the Node module, which the module implementing the *node* theme hook. (See the first code lines of [node_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_theme/7), the [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) implementation done by the Node module.) There are other modules that can implement a preprocess function for the node *theme* hook, but for those modules, that preprocess function is named `MYMODULE_preprocess_node()`, not `template_preprocess_node()`.

A theme can implement both a theme hook (see [bartik_menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!bartik!template.php/function/bartik_menu_tree/7)) and a preprocess function (see [bartik_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!bartik!template.php/function/bartik_preprocess_node/7)). The difference is that `bartik_menu_tree()` overrides the default implementation ([theme_menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7)) when the current theme is the Bartik theme, while `bartik_preprocess_node()` doesn't override `template_preprocess_node()`, but it is executed after it. (See the documentation for [theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7).)

As for using two prefixes, the reason is to documenting the purpose of the function. Even if theme_ were used in both the cases, the difference between `theme_image()` and `theme_preprocess_node()` would still be clear, but it would require you to read what follows theme_. With the current implementation, you just read the first word of the function name.